# Importing a CSV into phpMyAdmin is putting all the data into the first column

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a CSV of four columns, Product Name, SKU, Quantity, and Weight.

When I import into phpMyAdmin into a matching mySQL table it puts the SKU,Quantity, and Weight in the correct columns but for some reason its putting all the data into the Product Name column.

So for my CSV I have this data

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

And when I upload it it goes into the columns like this

```
INSERT INTO `DataImport` VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
INSERT INTO `DataImport` VALUES ('e,f,g,h ', 'f', 'g', 'h')
```

I have never seen it put the whole row of CSV data into the first column before and have successfully imported much more complicated CSVs in the past. Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: maybe you have some weird character on your csv row? Can you post the exact row that is being saved into Product Name?

Comment: Yeah I thought it was something like that which is why I simplified my data down to a,b,c,d for the columns. I made a new excel spreadsheet too to put the abcd data in in case that was causing the problem and it still happened.

Comment: Did you try quotes? So 'a','b','c','d'?

Comment: Yeah I did with " it inserted it like:
`INSERT INTO DataImport VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')# 1 row affected. INSERT INTO DataImport VALUES ('"e","f","g","h" e', 'f', 'g', 'h')#`

Answer (score 0):

bug report- Importing a CSV file under 4.3.3 results in all entries except the first row ignoring comma separators and filling the first column up to its limit...
http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4670/